# What is the difference between HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped & HttpContextScoped

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, structuremap, ioc-container

Simply, what is the difference between HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped & HttpContextScoped?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HttpContext always uses HttpContext (and fails if not running within a web request). HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped uses the HttpContext when available - if not, it falls back to caching per thread.