# How to stop Structure Map from returning the incorrect object from session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, structuremap

Some of the time Structure Map seems to be returning the incorrect object, this seems to happen when the given web server hosting our web app is under heavy load. The object in question is our own class containing properties for Server and Database name that is used to build a connection string.

Our web application has 2 parts, an ASPX web forms section that heavily uses session and a new part that is in MVC that lives within an area of the web forms project. Both of these areas share the same session. The database connection information is built at login and is stored in session. The web forms area directly gets the database information from session and this is working perfectly fine.

```
Dim dbInfo as DbInfo = me.Session("dbInfo")
```

The MVC area gets the database information inject via structure map which in turn gets the object from session.

```
Public Class WebRegistry
    Inherits Registry

    Public Sub New()
        [For](Of IDbInfo)().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(Function() GetDatabaseInfoFromSession())
    End Sub

    <CLSCompliant(False)>
    Public Shared Function GetDatabaseInfoFromSession() As IDbInfo            
        If HttpContext.Current.Session("dbInfo") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return HttpContext.Current.Session("dbInfo")
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see in the code above that both are accessing the same variable in session and seem to be returning the same value most of the time. But there seems to be some caching happening as the issue is that the old code is using the correct connection (the one that user has logged on with) and the structure map method seems to be caching another database connection.

The way we similated the same behaviour is manaully instantiating the dbInfo in the function GetDatabaseInfoFromSession to another database.

Note that this code has been in production for over a year and we have previous versions of the code on the same web servers working perfectly fine. The latest version of the website started exhibiting this bizarre caching behaviour last week. Notable things that have changed recently are:

1. The application pool running the site is now 64bit
2. There have been new kemp load balancers put in place.

Things we already have looked at:

1. [What is the difference between HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped & HttpContextScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014061/what-is-the-difference-between-hybridhttporthreadlocalscoped-httpcontextscoped) (we aren't doing anything with thread so we think this is fine)
2. [Difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940742/difference-between-session-and-httpcontext-current-session) (we have the null check in the GetDatabaseInfoFromSession and our old code is not throwing HttpException)

Does structure map start caching at a machine level if it is under load with 64bit enabled or does structure map get confused with active sessions?